# Animation in JavaScript with Modulo

Tags: javascript, animation, modulo

Is it possible, to store the logged numbers from this loop in an array? I have to solve something like this: Some people turn up in rows of two. When they line up, one is remaining. Same as the show up in rows of three, four, five and six people. But as people turn up in rows of seven, no one is left (the result is 301).
I have to animate this "people", which show up, for every row separately, until 301. It should be a little game with user input (or just buttons). I tried with something like below, but I don't even know, if I'm completely wrong. 
I thought, that it would work, if I try to store the output in an array and making a for...in-loop, to display the "people-animation" for each number in the array. I would be so happy, if would get some help or just a little hint, thank you so much! I'm completely new to this and I'm desperate.
I already have a working animation-script (for one "people").

```
var seven = 7;
var six;
var five;
var four;
var three;
var two;

while (six != 1 || five != 1|| four != 1|| three != 1|| two != 1)
{six = seven % 6;
five = seven % 5;
four = seven % 4;
three = seven % 3;
two = seven % 2;
console.log(seven);
seven += 7;}
```

Comment: Firstly, it is certainly possible to add those values to an array. But to be more of help I need some more info. You say that it is a game. Does the user control the amount of people that show up. And the maximum of each row is 7 people? In the array, what values do you need to make your animation? Could you make an example of how your arrays should be?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to divide the number sequence in rows.

```js
var seven = [[]];
var six = [[]];
var five = [[]];
var four = [[]];
var three = [[]];
var two = [[]];

cnt = 1;

while (cnt <= 301) {
  seven[seven.length - 1].push(cnt);
  six[six.length - 1].push(cnt);
  five[five.length - 1].push(cnt);
  four[four.length - 1].push(cnt);
  three[three.length - 1].push(cnt);
  two[two.length - 1].push(cnt);
  if (!(cnt % 7) && (cnt < 301)) seven.push([]);
  if (!(cnt % 6) && (cnt < 301)) six.push([]);
  if (!(cnt % 5) && (cnt < 301)) five.push([]);
  if (!(cnt % 4) && (cnt < 301)) four.push([]);
  if (!(cnt % 3) && (cnt < 301)) three.push([]);
  if (!(cnt % 2) && (cnt < 301)) two.push([]);
  
  cnt++;
} 

console.log(seven);
console.log(six);
console.log(five);
console.log(four);
console.log(three);
console.log(two);
```

Here's an improved version:

```js
var rows = {}; // object to keep the rows
var list = [...Array(8).keys()].slice(2); //creates a 2 to 7 range in an array
list.map(e=>rows[e] = [[]]); // initializes the rows object with empty array to store sequences

cnt = 1; //counter
while (cnt <= 301) { 
  //for each row type (2 to 7)
  list.forEach(row=> { 
        // get last row list and put current number
        rows[row][rows[row].length -1].push(cnt);
        // if there are already enough elements in that row type 
        // add another row in this row type
        if (!(cnt % row) && (cnt < 301)) rows[row].push([]);
  });  
  cnt++;
} 

console.log(rows);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Wow, this is just perfect, thank you soso much! :) You're a hero!

Comment: I have two more questions: The result is 301 for this calculation, but the program should calculate this by itself. The result (301) is "unknown" in the beginning. My code in my post above shows the calculation for 301. Is it possible, to store the outcome from my while-loop in a variable and put this in your code (in your first version), instead of the number 301?

Comment: And: How am I able to display a picture for every number in your arrays (your first version)? I think, it has to be a for...in-loop? I have an animation in another script (which "walks" over the screen). Is it possible, to reference the "animation-script" in this "calculation-script"? Or does it have to be one big thing? Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Nenia I think that at the moment this is enough helping with your homework. Now please push yourself a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understand your question correctly and that my effort is of any use to you. If I think I know what you mean is that you want to add rows divided into columns. For example `7 people divided over 3 columns` equals:

```
...
...
.
```

or in an array with numbers:

```
[
  3,
  3,
  1
]
```

And that the length of each column can be dynamically set, by either you or the user, but adding 7 people (in your case) with each set of rows.

I've build a class with which you can create an object which stores all of your values and can do the calculations needed when adding a row. You would be able to use this in your game and let you are the user decide in how many columns people should be added.

Try it out and let me know if I understood your question correctly as mine and @NelsonTeixeira's answer differ so vastly.

```js
class Crowd {

  /**
   * Store maxColumnLength and setup the default peopleLimit.
   */
  constructor(maxColumnLength, peopleLimit = 301) {
    this.maxColumnLength = maxColumnLength;
    this.peopleLimit = peopleLimit;
    this.totalPeople = 0;
    this.rows = [];
  }
  
  /**
   * Adds a new set of rows to the main rows collection
   *
   * @param {number} columnLength
   * @return {this}
   */
  addPeopleInColumnsOf(columnLength) {
    if (columnLength <= this.maxColumnLength && this.totalPeople + this.maxColumnLength <= this.peopleLimit) {
    
      // Create rows and calculate columns.
      let row = [];
      const amountOfFullRows = Math.floor(this.maxColumnLength / columnLength);
      const peopleInLastRow = this.maxColumnLength % columnLength;
      
      // Add all the full rows to the array.
      for (let i = 0; i < amountOfFullRows; i++) {
        row.push(columnLength);
      }
      
      // Add the last row to the array.
      if (peopleInLastRow !== 0) {
        row.push(peopleInLastRow);
      }
      
      // Push new rows to main row collection.
      // And add the total.
      this.rows.push(row);
      this.totalPeople += this.maxColumnLength;
    }
    
    return this;
  }
  
  /**
   * Outputs each row in the console.
   */
  showRows() {
    this.rows.forEach(row => {
      console.log(row);
    });
  }

}

/** 
 * Create an instance with a maximum column 
 * length of 7 and start adding people in columns of...
 */
const crowd = new Crowd(7)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(4)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(5)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(6)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(2)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(3)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(4)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(8) // This one will silently fail.
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(1)
  .addPeopleInColumnsOf(6);

// Show the results
crowd.showRows();
console.log(crowd.totalPeople);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think, Nelson Teixeira's solution fits very good for my purpose. But my description wasn't clear enough, I'm really sorry! Anyway, I'm very thankful for your time and work! :)